# Turning this implicit function into an explicit one

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y^2+3y - \sin2x + 2 = 0$$

Any hints?

Comment: It's quadratic in $y$...

Comment: Try completing the square in $y$.

Comment: The formula looks like $y^2+by+c=0$, can you rearrange that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$y^2+3y - \sin(2x) + 2 = \left(y+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 - \sin(2x) - \frac{1}{4}=0$$
which implies
$$\left(y+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2=\sin(2x) +\frac{1}{4}.$$
Now, in order to go on, $\sin(2x) +\frac{1}{4}$ should be non-negative.

We are expecting to find two functions $y(x)$ defined in a suitable set $D\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Can you take it from here?